# How to resolve invalid column name on parquet file read itself in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I setup a standalone spark and a standalone HDFS.

I installed pyspark and was able to create spark session.

I uploaded one parquet file to HDFS under `/data` : `hdfs://localhost:9000/data`

I tried to create a dataframe out of this directory using PySpark

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local[*]').appName("test").getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.parquet("hdfs://localhost:9000/data").withColumnRenamed("Wafer ID", "Wafer_ID")
```

I am getting invalid column name even with `withColumnRenamed`.
[image]

I tried with the following code but I got same error for this as well

```
df = spark.read.parquet("hdfs://localhost:9000/data").select(col("Wafer ID").alias("Wafer_ID"))
```

I have means to change the column names manually (pandas) or use different file entirely but I want to know if there is a way to solve this problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to add backquotes when reading it or renamed it.
wrap it with ` within the string it self. (Its translate it to code section here so its probably invisible but .. "```Wafer ID```"

Comment: I tried it with `withColumnRenamed("\`Wafer ID\`", "Wafer_ID")`. Still got the same error. Same for `select(col("\`Wafer ID\`").alias("Wafer_ID"))`

Comment: Try with two backquotes.
Anyway seems like there is an open issue just for that:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-677

Comment: Yeah got the same error with double backquotes as well. I tested things to see if a 'good' column name will work or not with pyspark. I used pandas to change name to 'Wafer_ID' and loaded it as spark df. It worked

Comment: if you don't rename the column while reading the parquet file, what column name is assigned to the df?

Comment: There is no spark DF because it threw the error on execution @LuizViola

Comment: @JeevaBharathi  What @LuizViola meant was:
`df = spark.read.parquet("hdfs://localhost:9000/data"); df.show()`

This will show all cols with data.

Comment: @AkhilJain df = spark.read.parquet("hdfs://localhost:9000/data") fails with an error. That is what i meant by no spark df

Comment: @JeevaBharathi then either something wrong with the setup itself.

Is your `data` a folder? If yes then you might have to try 
`df = spark.read.parquet("hdfs://localhost:9000/data/");`

Additionally the title of the question should to be edited as it is misleading.

Comment: @AkhilJain I do not think the question is misleading since I fixed this issue manually by changing the column name from 'Wafer ID' to 'Wafer_ID' using Pandas and wrote it back to HDFS and it worked.

Comment: @JeevaBharathi Good to know you were able to sort it out.
By the way you could have tried with back tick i.e  `Wafer ID`.
See this example for reference https://mungingdata.com/pyspark/avoid-dots-periods-column-names/ (as an example)